# Which Weblogic 10.3 JAR contains weblogic.rmi.RemoteException

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, rmi

I am trying to track down the Weblogic 10.3 JAR that contains weblogic.rmi.RemoteException in order to solve a build path issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it in $BEA-HOME/modules/com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client_1.4.0.0.jar

It seems in 10.3 or (10g as Oracle are branding it) they have moved a lot of what was in $BEA-HOME/wlserver_10.x/server/lib/weblogic.jar into a seperate modules directory in the root of the bea install.

I also had to include $BEA-HOME/modules/com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.4.0.0.jar on my build path to use com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client_1.4.0.0.jar

The script above is useful, a slightly simpler version which will recurse through sub-directories searching each jar file it encounters for a specified class is

find -name "*.jar" -exec grep "" {} \;

e.g. find -name "*.jar" -exec grep "weblogic/rmi/RemoteException.class" {} \;

I found the tip courtesy of

http://snipplr.com/view/12702/find-in-which-jar-a-class-is-defined/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have WebLogic installed here, but I keep a shell/cygwin script around to find classes in jars:

```
#! /bin/sh

target=$1
for jf in `find . -name '*.jar' -type f -print`; do
  jar tvf $jf | awk "/\/$target\.class/ { print \"$jf: \" \$NF }"
done
```

Just call the script something like jarfind.sh and put it in your path somewhere. Then `jarfind.sh RemoteException` in your weblogic tree.

Answer (score 0):

It's in server/lib/weblogic.jar on my version 10.0.

Comment: That's where I expected it to be but it doesn't appear to be there in 10.3

Comment: That's surprising....I don't have 10.3 installed locally, so I can't check.  Funny that it's changed between 10.0 and 10.3.  When you open the JAR, do you sort by class name?  It's easy to miss if you sort by package.

Comment: I've tried sorting by both. The only class I have under weblogic.rmi is ForceCallByReference

Comment: Have just checked a 10.0 weblogic.jar and it is there, it seems to have been moved in 10.3 and I can not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The website [jarhoo](http://www.jarhoo.com/) claims to have searchable indexes of all common JAR files - but I haven't used it in years and you now seem to require a logon:

- [www.jarhoo.com](http://www.jarhoo.com)

The scripts given in the other answers will obviously give better results for your CLASSPATH :-)

Comment: I find findjar.com works really well and is free. Although it wasn't able to help me this time.